# Neo4j db slow running it on Mac M1 with neo4j desktop

Tags: neo4j, apple-m1, neo4j-desktop

I downloaded the neo4j desktop to my Mac M1, I notice that the same import which takes a few minutes on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine (same running a neo4j db in desktop setup) is extremely slow. (48 hours for the same query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to some neo4j folks on the conference:
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-on-mac-osx/

***you need to:***

1. `brew install java`
2. `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

I already had a neo4j desktop on my machine so to make it work I reinstalled the neo4j desktop and created a new db, now the import flies.

(And you probably do not need to reinstall just create a new db)